# How to remap Super/Windows(left) key to control key in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

Could anyone please tell me how to remap my Super(left) key to Ctrl key in Ubuntu Linux?

I mean Super(left) should work as control key..

Answer (score 9):

Save the following (untested) code to a file and use it as an argument for the xmodmap command:

```
clear Control
clear Mod4
keysym Super_L = Control_L
add    Control = Control_L Control_R
add    Mod4    = Super_L Super_R
```

Comment: This is just perfect for a mac keyboard.

Comment: Worked for me on crunchbang

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using GNOME 3.

in terminal write

```
$ gnome-control-center
```

click on "keyboard" then click on "layout settings" then "options..." then "Alt/Win key behavior" then choose "control is mapped to Win keys( and the usual CTRL keys)

UPDATE: if you want to disable the original CTRL key then from "options.." choose "compose key position" and check both left/right CTRL.

Comment: Thanks! But small disadvantage is both super keys are acting as Ctrl key. Is there any way to make only left Super key to act as Ctrl..

Comment: @Sandy i've updated the post. applying the update will make only left Super key to act as Ctrl. feel free to accept the answer if it did work.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked..

Comment: @Sandy did you do both of them i mean the answer and the update? it did work for me on fedora 16!

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 there's no such option anymore

Comment: @YuriBaburov, you can use `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wayland xmodmap may not work. use input remap tool, and map super_l to control_l
[image]
re

https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper